# xcode file path

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My question is very simple, I have a text file that I put in the folder "other sources" in Xcode, and I want a use this text file in my program but I don't know what is his file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is in an Xcode group and not a referenced directory, then it will be placed in the root of the app's main bundle.  So if you're trying to get at `foo.txt`, you can access it like this:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"txt"];
```